# Is it possible to download and AdWords report in PDF format?

Tags: pdf, report, google-ads-api

I am attempting to download an AdWords report in pdf format but i can't find the .pdf option in the dropdown menu. Is pdf not an option for Table reports?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't go to Report Editor, but try to download data directly from Campaigns interface, choose 'Download' option and there will be a .pdf option.